# Xcode 4.1 fails to install on my Snow Leopard Mac OS X 10.6.3

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode4, osx-snow-leopard

I recently downloaded Xcode 4.1 to install on Snow Leopard Mac OS X 10.6.3, however it fails to install. When I clicked to install the package, it gives me a "com.apple.installer.pagecontroller error-1" and says it fails to install. Does anyone know why this might be the problem? Thanks in advance!! (I have paid the $99 and joined Apple development).

Comment: Umm, thanks guys! I actually got the problem solved, but now I am facing problems with Xcode connecting to online database. But thanks a lot really appreciate it!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Original answer:*

Xcode 4.1 is for Lion only, and won't run on Snow Leopard.

For Snow Leopard, you'll have to use Xcode 4.0.2 instead. (Or upgrade to Lion.)

*Update after helpful comment by @gcamp:*

- Xcode 4.1 for Lion was released Jul 20, 2011.
- Xcode 4.1 for Snow Leopard was released Aug 29, 2011.

How did you download 4.1? The version currently available in the App Store lists "Mac OS X 10.7 or later" as a requirement, so it's the Lion-only version. To get the Snow Leopard version, you have to download it directly from [iOS Dev Center](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action).

Comment: Thats actually false, I am running Xcode 4.2 on Snow Leopard *10.6.8* as seen in this screenshot: http://snapplr.com/00md, also, see the iOS Dev Center: http://snapplr.com/mwep.

Comment: @WrightsCS: that's a developer preview though, no ? I think the actual release version of Xcode 4.2 is Lion-only ?

Comment: @Paul actually, 4.1 is the latest for Snow Leopard, I am partially wrong: http://snapplr.com/z2c5, also, he has access to beta software as well, so there is more choice.

Comment: @WrightsCS Jon made a really understandable mistake. The Snow Leopard version of Xcode 4.1 is out since a couple of days only. When Lion came out officially, Xcode 4.1 was available only for Lion. (Xcode 4.2 was always available for both Lion and Snow Leopard)

Comment: @WrightsCS And because you run 4.2 on 10.6.8 means nothing about the ability to run 4.1 on Lion...

Comment: @gcamp, maybe, but 4.1 has been out for almost 1 week now.

Comment: @gcam, also, if I can run 4.2 on SNow Leopard, then 4.1 is obviously supported. Snow Leopard is what Andy is trying to install 4.1 on, so it really means everything in comparison.

Comment: `can run 4.2 on SNow Leopard, then 4.1 is obviously supported.` not true. Xcode 4.1 could really have been an Lion-only version. Especially that almost every new feature was Lion-related.

Comment: @WrightCS While the 4.2 beta is available for both OS versions, 4.1 was initially a Lion-only release. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Xcode 4.1 requires 10.6.7, as stated in the [read me](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/xcode_4.1_for_snow_leopard_21110/xcode_4.1_for_snow_leopard_readme.pdf).

You just need to [update your Mac](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1338) (and make sure you have the right version of Xcode 4.1).

Answer (score 3):

X-Code 4 requires Snow Leopard Mac OS X 10.6.7 or Later...Please check the read me file in Apple website..hope this helps you..

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you may have a corrupted installation file. Have you tried redownloading it? I know it's a rather large download, but it's likely it was corrupted along it's journey.

**Before trying a complete re-download of the installer, try rebooting your computer to see if that helps.**